# HttpRequest describable to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using asp.net core v2.1 with C# and made a small website. This website has `ExceptionsTracker` that catching all the unhandeled exceptions.

```
internal class ExceptionTracker : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // ...
        string httpRequestInformation;
        try
        {
            httpRequestInformation = context.HttpContext.Request.ToString(); // The problem here.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            httpRequestInformation = string.Empty;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

The main idea behind this is to write all the exception to log and be able to reproduce it on development (run the same query that made the exception).

When I made this line with the previous .NET framework (v4.6)
`context.HttpContext.Request.ToString()`, the return value was a string that contain all the information from the request (requested URL, headers, body, ...). When I'm doing it with .net core, the return value is

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest
```

Do you have better solution then to construct this string manually?

Thanks!

### Update

According to @kennyzx recommendation, I made a short Method extension to solve this problem.

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static string GetDetails(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        string baseUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString.Value}";
        StringBuilder sbHeaders = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var header in request.Headers)
            sbHeaders.Append($"{header.Key}: {header.Value}\n");

        string body = "no-body";
        if (request.Body.CanSeek)
        {
            request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.Body))
                body = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return $"{request.Protocol} {request.Method} {baseUrl}\n\n{sbHeaders}\n{body}";
    }
}
```

If you have better solution, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

You get

> a string that contain all the information from the request (requested URL, headers, body, ...).

by calling `ToString()` in v4.6 because the class overrides `System.Object.ToString()` method, but in asp.net core v2.1 it does not, so it just prints the full qualified name of the class, which is the default return value of the `System.Object.ToString()`.

You can do it yourself, by constructing the string from the [various properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.internal.defaulthttprequest?view=aspnetcore-2.1) it provides. You can write an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) like

```
public static class MyExtensionClass 
{
    public static string GetDetails(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest request)
    {
        return request.PathString.Value + " " + ... ; //Construct your string here 
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
httpRequestInformation = context.HttpContext.Request.GetDetails();
```

Comment: This solution is the "manual" one. It defenetly working but less good then the previous solution (.net framework v4.6). Attached my code in the main thread.

Comment: I check the link I provided in the answer again, there are already some extension methods like GetDisplayUrl defined for this class, so you can enhance your method by using the existing methods. But if you really want so many detailed info in a single method, you have to write it yourself.